# Is there any way to extract more than 50k records inside execute method of batch?

Tags: apex, batch, webservices, governorlimits, batchapexerrorevent

I have a batch working on approx 40k records in chunks of 200 records. 
Inside execute of the batch I am querying from one abject returning more than 50k records. Getting 500001 error. How to remove this error ? Any alternative solution to get rid of this.
Start Query-

```
String str = 'SELECT 
        id, EQ_UsageSchedule__c, EQ_ValidationError__c, EQ_ProcessStatus__c,
        APTS_Legacy_ExternalID__c, 
        EQ_ServiceCode__c, EQ_Account__c, EQ_AssetLineItem__c,
        EQ_AccountLocation__c, EQ_IssueNumber__c, 
        EQ_SourceSystem__c, EQ_RecordKey__c, EQ_WorkId__c, EQ_QuantityID__c, 
        EQ_LoadMonth__c, EQ_Quantity__c 
    FROM EQ_TempSSP1Data__c 
    WHERE EQ_WorkId__c = :workid';
```

Execute Query:

```
for(Apttus_Config2__AssetLineItem__c x : [SELECT 
        id, Apttus_Config2__AccountId__r.Apttus_Billing__Active__c,
        Apttus_Config2__StartDate__c, Apttus_Config2__EndDate__c,
        Apttus_Config2__BillToAccountId__c, EQ_AssetFeeCode__c,
        EQ_BillToLocationId__c,
        Apttus_Config2__AssetStatus__c, Apttus_Config2__LocationId__c 
    FROM Apttus_Config2__AssetLineItem__c 
    WHERE 
        (Apttus_Config2__BillToAccountId__c IN :accountIds) AND 
        Apttus_Config2__PriceType__c = 'Usage' AND 
        EQ_AssetFeeCode__c != null AND 
        Apttus_Config2__AssetStatus__c = 'Activated']
) {
    system.debug('value of asset line item-->'+x);

    assetLineItems1.add(x);            
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to do batch on another object (that one, which gives 50k error)? and query first one from there?

Comment: @kurunve I can not call a batch from execute. I dont think that is possible.

Comment: What I mean is that instead of having batch on first object (40k of records) -- do batch on second one (with more than 50k of records), and then query related records of first type.

Comment: @Kurunve Actually here situation is, both the queries are expected to return more than 50k records. Also query which is in execute is completely dependednt on result of outer query.

Comment: It might help if you include some general idea on what your trying to achieve. Perhaps there is a different workaround. I have no idea if this would work, and it might be a bad idea anyway, but perhaps you could do a @ ReadOnly query in a scheduled batch, and then use an @ future method to do your update.

Comment: @Kasper  i dont think this will help. As the query in start can return more thsn 50k records. Need batching for that also. In schedule batch that wont be possible.

Comment: You can have more then 50k records in a scheduled batch. You just need the schedulable interface for the read only annotation. Another option may be to pre-process your data. Can you give us a global outline of what your trying to achieve? (Are you summing data, validating records, will all the records you query be updated?)

Comment: @Kasper I am extracting records in batches from start query, perform some validations. After this processing I am able to get accountIds in the list correspending to each tempSSp1 record. I need to get all the Asset line items related to those accounts and find the correct mapping of tempSSP1 and Assetlineitem and then update the tempSSp1 with the correct ALI record. I am not sure if you get this. In short I am updating tempSSp1 with the correct ALI record after finding the correct ALI .

Comment: Sound complicated :). Pre-processing your data may help though. Maybe you could also lower the batch size to prevent part of your problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104324/discussion-between-suren-and-kasper).

Answer (score 4):

Restructure your query so that the `start` method returns the data that there is the high volume of. So if you are presently returning a parent object and then querying the child object in `execute`, instead query the child object in `start` and include its related parent object in the `start` query too or query the parent object in `execute`.

This may or may not be logically possible, but it is the first thing to consider.

Comment: I can not use query in start returning more than 50 k due to some dependency on the outer query records precessing. I need batching on outer query at first place.

Comment: Hi @Suren, I suggest you include the queries in your question.

Comment: Sure adding that piece of code.

Comment: Hi @Suren, You haven't provided quite enough info e.g. how is the `accountIds` variable populated from the data that originates in the `start` method.

Comment: .@Keith  Actualyy there is a lot of logic behind this. Not able to post the code here.